# Javascript simple style.display function only works at random

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have been given an assignment to code my own tic tac toe game. I am fairly new to coding, but absolutely love it. I have for now set up a simple function to just hide the "O", and thus only displaying the X. It's a long way to go, but either way I'd like to start off like this.

However, when I click one of the squares, the "O" only hides at random. Sometimes the first time I click, sometimes after four times. Does anybody know what's wrong?

This is the function I'm working with, and this is how one square is built in html:

```js
function hideO() {
  document.getElementById("O" + event.target.id).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="square" >
  <button class="1" id="1"  onclick="hideO()">
      <p class="X1" id="X1">X</p>
      <p class="O1" id="O1">O</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

[Here's all the code I've got.](https://jsfiddle.net/raivo/cbxvadzp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `event.target` returns the element you actually clicked on, so when you think you have clicked on `.square`, you have actually clicked on the `p` inside it. One solution here is to use `event.currentTarget`. It will always return the element to which the click method was attached:

```
function hideO() {
  document.getElementById("O" + event.currentTarget.id).style.display = "none";
}
```

Also, I have no idea why you are making `.grid` call `hideO`. I would remove that.

**Edit:** this seems to break because `event.currentTarget` is only valid at the time the event is fired. You can try an alternative solution.

Amend your `hideO()` function as follows:

```
function hideO(btn) {
  btn.querySelector("#O" + btn.id).style.display = "none";
}
```

And instead of `onclick="hideO()"`, use `onclick="hideO(this)"`, so that the button that was clicked gets passed in as a parameter. Once you have that button in your function, you can get the "O" element inside it.

Comment: Now it works every time on the first two grids/ squares, but not at all for the other. Should I take a different approach to this, or does anybody know why it's so weird

Comment: This seems to happen because `event.currentTarget` is only valid at the time of firing the event. See updated answer.

Comment: It's only changing the first two grids, thereafter it's showing the same error as before. What could be the error?

Comment: I think you meant it's *not changing the first two grids but changing the rest*. That is because in the first two grids you've assigned `onclick(this)` to `.square` rather than the button itself.